# Simple closed loops on a genus g surface

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $P$ be a point on a compact orientable genus g surface, $S$ (a Riemann surface, but I'm not worried about the complex structure). Is the number of homotopy classes of simple closed loops based at $P$ finite?

Answer (score 2):

No. Start with a torus and construct a lines that wind around the "soul" of the torus once and $n$ times around the meridian. Pick one point as base point where all loops start and end. Now fix another point and push all these loops a little bit away from it, so that you can take a connected sum with a surface of genus $g-1$ at that point. Then you get a surface of genus $g$ with infinitely many free loops in different homotopy classes.